Difference in the effects of Gayatri mantra and the ashttotara shatanamavali of a deity
Most of the deities have a Gayatri mantra associated to them . Also these deities also have their ashttotara shatanamavali which also helps in getting some blessings of the deity. My question is , which one gives a better results and can we get an increased amount of blessing if any one of them is chanted for a very long period of time ?
